# FindQScintilla.cmake

Tags: cmake

I'm using QScintilla in my project.  There's no good `FindQScintilla.cmake` out there, so I'm writing one myself.  However, I don't really know what I'm doing.  This is my attempt; it works, but I don't know how it'll work in reality:

```
find_path(QSCINTILLA_INCLUDE_DIR
  NAMES Qsci qsciglobal.h
  PATHS "${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS}" /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5
  PATH_SUFFIXES Qsci
)

find_library(QSCINTILLA_LIBRARY
  NAMES qt5scintilla2 libqt5scintilla2
  PATHS ${Qt5Core_LIBRARIES}
)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

find_package_handle_standard_args(
  QScintilla
  FOUND_VAR QSCINTILLA_FOUND
  REQUIRED_VARS QSCINTILLA_INCLUDE_DIR QSCINTILLA_LIBRARY
  VERSION_VAR QSCINTILLA_VERSION
)

if(QSCINTILLA_LIBRARY AND QSCINTILLA_INCLUDE_DIR)
  set(QSCINTILLA_LIBRARIES ${QSCINTILLA_LIBRARY})
  set(QSCINTILLA_INCLUDE_DIRS ${QSCINTILLA_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

mark_as_advanced(QSCINTILLA_INCLUDE_DIR QSCINTILLA_LIBRARY)
```

My development environment is Ubuntu 16.04, but I want this package to work on all major platforms.

More specifically:

- Am I missing anything?
- How will this hold up on different operating systems?

  - I'm targeting Windows, Mac, and Linux, though if there's a quick and easy way I can target another OS then I'll do that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall I think you have all the major pieces there, but I would also taking your find module a step further and create a target if QScintilla is found. You can do this by adding the following:

```
if(QSCINTILLA_LIBRARY AND QSCINTILLA_INCLUDE_DIR)

  set(QSCINTILLA_LIBRARIES ${QSCINTILLA_LIBRARY})
  set(QSCINTILLA_INCLUDE_DIRS ${QSCINTILLA_INCLUDE_DIR})

  if(NOT TARGET QScintilla::QScintilla)
      add_library(QScintilla::QScintilla UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
      set_target_properties(QScintilla::QScintilla PROPERTIES
           IMPORTED_IMPLIB ${QSCINTILLA_LIBRARY}
           INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${QSCINTILLA_INCLUDE_DIR})
  endif(NOT TARGET QScintilla::QSintilla)

endif(QSCINTILLA_LIBRARY AND QSCINTILLA_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Now you can use the library like so: `target_link_libraries(MyProject PUBLIC QScintilla::QScintilla)`. Feel free to change the imported target name.

---

One minor thing I would suggest (that you can see in the code above ^) it to have your `if()` conditions match inside the corresponding `end()` call. So if you have `if(condition)`, the matching `end()` should also look like `end(condition)`.

---

As for cross platform support it's difficult to say without trying it on multiple platforms. I'm not sure about your `find_path` call. The use of `${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS}` should be portable enough but it's tough to say.

One other nuance with find modules that I personally find can be troublesome is that on windows, if the library is a shared library you need to find the path to the `.lib` file and the `.dll` since that binary file isn't necessarily on the user's environment path. This is more of a nice to have and something I do for all find modules I write, but I work mostly on windows anyway.